# Cannot connect to a remote server using Atom and Remote-FTP

Tags: ssh, atom-editor, ubuntu-server

I cannot connect to a remote server from Atom using the Remote-FTP package and SSH keys. Every method and solution I have tried gives me the error `Error: All configured authentication methods failed`.

The server is `Ubuntu Server 22.04` running on `Oracle Virtual Box` on a `Windows 10` Machine. Both `Windows` and `Ubuntu Server` have all the latest updates installed.

I can connect to the server with the same keys using `PuTTY`, `MobaXterm_Personal_22.0 (SSH and SFTP)` and `HeidiSQL`, but `Atom` and `Remote-FTP` are the only apps that will not connect.

What can be done to solve the problem? They only way I can connect is using the `username` and `password` method, which I do not wish to use. Can you please help?

I've posted the keys I use. These very same keys work perfect with `puTTY` and `MobaXterm_Personal_22.0`, but not with `Atom` and `Remote-FTP`

**This is my public key (key_public)**

`---- BEGIN SSH2 PUBLIC KEY ---- Comment: "rsa-key-20220502" AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAACAQDhECUXoSjBuB7ymAJCvNNV5x+hyLvBHW9L vbkJR9kWwLJFm+qZyY4caxHPKYpu8/llZCDEB8S43N3SgwuQjtAL5V6JUh0BPGf0 Sqr+do9zcKVpCtdCpEMIIYVxPHCSePDPcB8SpGBaaIxNZj62d/AmXPVuPTmqQ6Kw 23jnQgp7dyfYpf6Nyr06ncVVHZRwfYOBy2dULaWs+mKYocCUuPYaTeSPerrjshgP B74KZR3Z5eAo/yQH6dfzY7bPioeqj/dJCU2JGWn7/QCNQA3amOcewwkWetbwr1Px LZ9AZ3V/BoC32yROYsiDyMucJjehFVpcK+n7MbpNLdY+BUJhmZX8RE50wxgSWRce oN4wEUf7Nzb3UKrFRsXPsLq9zexIAP3I31HStgY87xHMTw3+5vTb209p6M6oBiaW Z7n+VEJkW1YuIsyU+XHitGvn6+Hs2gTx70qWGBbenW6fZlZUNm1qUes3sNHI9MD3 5odAOJQ4LTZrvHup2T8Q/1ELlMOygr7NWkJyj1j3AgVKFTye76G4zF3KvNFXc3+p W+Vx+auoetowB2Vfe5LZH3wlNYzWegwGMILep4xZsqFZVmUksZTgPftMTscNm1BY A6vHAp8/F2fVTSn/9tZa8me2yk3372E86AE7Q7vekYWO1eZjXiwd2+8Cy0WwHabJ T1OMonQ7yw==---- END SSH2 PUBLIC KEY ----`

**This is my private key (key_private.ppk)**

`PuTTY-User-Key-File-3: ssh-rsa Encryption: none Comment: rsa-key-20220502 Public-Lines: 12 AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAACAQDhECUXoSjBuB7ymAJCvNNV5x+hyLvBHW9L vbkJR9kWwLJFm+qZyY4caxHPKYpu8/llZCDEB8S43N3SgwuQjtAL5V6JUh0BPGf0 Sqr+do9zcKVpCtdCpEMIIYVxPHCSePDPcB8SpGBaaIxNZj62d/AmXPVuPTmqQ6Kw 23jnQgp7dyfYpf6Nyr06ncVVHZRwfYOBy2dULaWs+mKYocCUuPYaTeSPerrjshgP B74KZR3Z5eAo/yQH6dfzY7bPioeqj/dJCU2JGWn7/QCNQA3amOcewwkWetbwr1Px LZ9AZ3V/BoC32yROYsiDyMucJjehFVpcK+n7MbpNLdY+BUJhmZX8RE50wxgSWRce oN4wEUf7Nzb3UKrFRsXPsLq9zexIAP3I31HStgY87xHMTw3+5vTb209p6M6oBiaW Z7n+VEJkW1YuIsyU+XHitGvn6+Hs2gTx70qWGBbenW6fZlZUNm1qUes3sNHI9MD3 5odAOJQ4LTZrvHup2T8Q/1ELlMOygr7NWkJyj1j3AgVKFTye76G4zF3KvNFXc3+p W+Vx+auoetowB2Vfe5LZH3wlNYzWegwGMILep4xZsqFZVmUksZTgPftMTscNm1BY A6vHAp8/F2fVTSn/9tZa8me2yk3372E86AE7Q7vekYWO1eZjXiwd2+8Cy0WwHabJ T1OMonQ7yw== Private-Lines: 28 AAACADovQVeli3Lhleaj09nLFVvc/7mEur2HTZGoP+EdWQtfz/bdAz608+924sjK 9YYPvwcuZqYnV/1u5E4bIO9DbJfWuaUIvIToR/vJHgHhRt7SXYEVk2cgLlA40lXf CT9k0uTeGLpqEprs8nDEISxtP4G7gJv6aiERkUrlwpEO6sTWnk+NQo0Hv/oadby2 g/y9BjWVD2ac0nsw1DKfhrksRDuyrYdGdHCPR1cDamcnkxsVKemPZJJDK1g6DDYF m2NGCukv5YKvNk42L2FVEP/VjdLPG1dbdJwOx8XPRJ+S37ZySO6/UdiOA0bGr5Tz 8GfNrGmt1LTjO0Xetseb9nhjC3oLT+/3FGu+2aE0l62fSSNwPlTv0fbhJYFhUQrf rmjbZWOy6CS8XnMclzA1d37Y380diJSj+TpngeB6e7+hxTOobCL2VQLNd01JBXZZ JUHGnMrTiPwS0xu738mu9UwRqXsi7yvf+wax1DGLdbJ8bMuPuxejSu4cG9oZSs1N huy2uvzOY3bxyA9YpdCl2iZBpJ87PR/GjXdBSVTIbiwsWZUHKMmUw9b6npjqWV5O f6RkZuw7autNmyfXm1ztNjx9zUxfPkWJd78qMRrH74SWXJh/Tx+GKADov9AzZTfw phnKHZgb+lk8Bt+EJDsrTS4rJ4ulavm1F8FWrh+jxgfv7/VJAAABAQD004ODdruX 5WeQg8lwhIlO0HiYwham11J/XUevehqZPZhGBnzXCn0OkEYwseWDVPpWGNRqz6XV KC2xSSsRiEzTpZVwrPliquLp/NoQf8rUWcrlCKI3/Rofve3g5XhL2e2gnMGCJ8UD 6P3Cf9NZEXkMgI0WDcmeQO5QVQZMC04Slf7JkxNsREHu/eTDgDgxYycfVqaMlIcv chl0vn8YaJSdpdzfnERRExmdPGg3tctyq5B/WcVJt2gfR/RKyaWTWm5/QWlMAdKg GuUqiGevj58p/1ALHOTHTpiMwISUbAXk513cZkUdtv6ZyNQyH/EascDoFBRI3R0U agAF1oeWNJcPAAABAQDrVbk46nDzToNPf1cgTmVcdbUgFx48oFHYrl6sVbuxuRog Y/wB1pKrNdQS2c4rJo1Lh6Dr8ygyG44xn/ruKWHEw/YFHsoxzJAv7ZNLdNMTuhbS mN5JbRaBahQRs9bHmr4gIUHHwUI5aoxvnjvfBeHLzOQZTEvqR0cBKpv7KOyUbTrJ 6moaUTvmkwh929PSV4RGoCPJDR2lLtjmhKnsZsKvShn85gOxrMQpzxJwDapfbhvv wcEiYli3bXO5G27cFQfVn1PeFI+MzLmmj+0VXcILyLmjbIGpc/ObA3MXtVXtLEfZ 5z8AMsjN/lhIuFtxdeDrWrISCEKOb4jBicbIOi+FAAABAQDYRQJ6KWAneh/lXiXs qeMM/IWHVenVpFs7gLjfuZBB04siC17/oeKjq5RtwY4/hzX3Y/FqjamNjXH1o7hK 8Tsv4AbOgiehjgfLE0uHpjlyaIr8R9s9v5Y5PzLSvCm0fwm2JmyUTcuLHN6IZekY xokcabwS/VvXRu3IFmZp2chMyT56Zknnvz+4dXw8xpWjELusUqg6cIEuCNORTbks 18lQhwbrzMvihoMWoyTymsupXc2XJbYY+nzzyebdM1MPRxQPR61kAZQcPNS5uTs0 0cA0glfrZiPIbhztL64aR6rKhf6ajPfKwjVmAUS9olKHLuQgiCvasKlVxRXfW+Bu mdEO Private-MAC: 62855df83e8562bf178ad8077cdcbfebaf4472a1401c15f68d32ae5d79ed641b`

**atom.ppk used in Remote-FTP config file.**

`-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY----- MIIJKQIBAAKCAgEA4RAlF6Eowbge8pgCQrzTVecfoci7wR1vS725CUfZFsCyRZvq mcmOHGsRzymKbvP5ZWQgxAfEuNzd0oMLkI7QC+VeiVIdATxn9Eqq/naPc3ClaQrX QqRDCCGFcTxwknjwz3AfEqRgWmiMTWY+tnfwJlz1bj05qkOisNt450IKe3cn2KX+ jcq9Op3FVR2UcH2DgctnVC2lrPpimKHAlLj2Gk3kj3q647IYDwe+CmUd2eXgKP8k B+nX82O2z4qHqo/3SQlNiRlp+/0AjUAN2pjnHsMJFnrW8K9T8S2fQGd1fwaAt9sk TmLIg8jLnCY3oRVaXCvp+zG6TS3WPgVCYZmV/EROdMMYElkXHqDeMBFH+zc291Cq xUbFz7C6vc3sSAD9yN9R0rYGPO8RzE8N/ub029tPaejOqAYmlme5/lRCZFtWLiLM lPlx4rRr5+vh7NoE8e9KlhgW3p1un2ZWVDZtalHrN7DRyPTA9+aHQDiUOC02a7x7 qdk/EP9RC5TDsoK+zVpCco9Y9wIFShU8nu+huMxdyrzRV3N/qVvlcfmrqHraMAdl X3uS2R98JTWM1noMBjCC3qeMWbKhWVZlJLGU4D37TE7HDZtQWAOrxwKfPxdn1U0p //bWWvJntspN9+9hPOgBO0O73pGFjtXmY14sHdvvAstFsB2myU9TjKJ0O8sCAwEA AQKCAgA6L0FXpYty4ZXmo9PZyxVb3P+5hLq9h02RqD/hHVkLX8/23QM+tPPvduLI yvWGD78HLmamJ1f9buROGyDvQ2yX1rmlCLyE6Ef7yR4B4Ube0l2BFZNnIC5QONJV 3wk/ZNLk3hi6ahKa7PJwxCEsbT+Bu4Cb+mohEZFK5cKRDurE1p5PjUKNB7/6GnW8 toP8vQY1lQ9mnNJ7MNQyn4a5LEQ7sq2HRnRwj0dXA2pnJ5MbFSnpj2SSQytYOgw2 BZtjRgrpL+WCrzZONi9hVRD/1Y3SzxtXW3ScDsfFz0Sfkt+2ckjuv1HYjgNGxq+U 8/BnzaxprdS04ztF3rbHm/Z4Ywt6C0/v9xRrvtmhNJetn0kjcD5U79H24SWBYVEK 365o22VjsugkvF5zHJcwNXd+2N/NHYiUo/k6Z4Hgenu/ocUzqGwi9lUCzXdNSQV2 WSVBxpzK04j8EtMbu9/JrvVMEal7Iu8r3/sGsdQxi3WyfGzLj7sXo0ruHBvaGUrN TYbstrr8zmN28cgPWKXQpdomQaSfOz0fxo13QUlUyG4sLFmVByjJlMPW+p6Y6lle Tn+kZGbsO2rrTZsn15tc7TY8fc1MXz5FiXe/KjEax++EllyYf08fhigA6L/QM2U3 8KYZyh2YG/pZPAbfhCQ7K00uKyeLpWr5tRfBVq4fo8YH7+/1SQKCAQEA9NODg3a7 l+VnkIPJcISJTtB4mMIWptdSf11Hr3oamT2YRgZ81wp9DpBGMLHlg1T6VhjUas+l 1SgtsUkrEYhM06WVcKz5Yqri6fzaEH/K1FnK5QiiN/0aH73t4OV4S9ntoJzBgifF A+j9wn/TWRF5DICNFg3JnkDuUFUGTAtOEpX+yZMTbERB7v3kw4A4MWMnH1amjJSH L3IZdL5/GGiUnaXc35xEURMZnTxoN7XLcquQf1nFSbdoH0f0Ssmlk1puf0FpTAHS oBrlKohnr4+fKf9QCxzkx06YjMCElGwF5Odd3GZFHbb+mcjUMh/xGrHA6BQUSN0d FGoABdaHljSXDwKCAQEA61W5OOpw806DT39XIE5lXHW1IBcePKBR2K5erFW7sbka IGP8AdaSqzXUEtnOKyaNS4eg6/MoMhuOMZ/67ilhxMP2BR7KMcyQL+2TS3TTE7oW 0pjeSW0WgWoUEbPWx5q+ICFBx8FCOWqMb5473wXhy8zkGUxL6kdHASqb+yjslG06 yepqGlE75pMIfdvT0leERqAjyQ0dpS7Y5oSp7GbCr0oZ/OYDsazEKc8ScA2qX24b 78HBImJYt21zuRtu3BUH1Z9T3hSPjMy5po/tFV3CC8i5o2yBqXPzmwNzF7VV7SxH 2ec/ADLIzf5YSLhbcXXg61qyEghCjm+IwYnGyDovhQKCAQASCifNnwkRlzC7YEqO hOWNLiVEtEBxCLqmcdwfXPLqybQXrNC0E6zFTvItEl6j/7X2dBvqxuQkQbKkNoz6 3L00dyX8yHITyB2yOhRjVNdAMGGX4Lv7PiYXoqoNgTsM88DjrclAaufEcv2HwF11 Wak+t5YtwtRRWd11g95T6h1Vl0HP3ot21cy57HFXynHZicHPOFZLU4Jmh5TCmmrJ BKO2vgr5Ww1Zn/uqL1JKkJWuHGAoUhgMZ3w/mdCxVgxiQC6WJ963YAcCDxlFuglR 0VZcBNkECJv+55asAF+EhDUm+blbzRlYqCw4bqjcDKh6XBCnyRr5h3lmEK1xwK36 7mMXAoIBAQDRcdbKL+TcthiprQSGzR7q/ht4dvrDLFALj4zUxeypTLtS7ol/vU+F rv+S02PpBYOlIA15UUyJ4/pWcjJquku4Sktv3SpIze3ZqhB4jH27RdhAECttn/fy r80ywCK8PR1PDSo1NOvSm+BnCqXwZJTDxBOR7FR4Kn2oLRrrmk2L//bdc5KA36F3 IY7iLL5FqvwfuzB+I/0pYRtLdfChZAeK6GFesfvBqqhfKVsYfSEPk7irVn6kMnEQ twnSSfcNSm5Rkl6a/SORRTdJZTi01l/4Cuok51Iy1O6PHK/W/t19mvZLmcJ5U7lh lCdQeTtxLF9EN9DZuZ46lEtbLFrNIvPdAoIBAQDYRQJ6KWAneh/lXiXsqeMM/IWH VenVpFs7gLjfuZBB04siC17/oeKjq5RtwY4/hzX3Y/FqjamNjXH1o7hK8Tsv4AbO giehjgfLE0uHpjlyaIr8R9s9v5Y5PzLSvCm0fwm2JmyUTcuLHN6IZekYxokcabwS /VvXRu3IFmZp2chMyT56Zknnvz+4dXw8xpWjELusUqg6cIEuCNORTbks18lQhwbr zMvihoMWoyTymsupXc2XJbYY+nzzyebdM1MPRxQPR61kAZQcPNS5uTs00cA0glfr ZiPIbhztL64aR6rKhf6ajPfKwjVmAUS9olKHLuQgiCvasKlVxRXfW+BumdEO -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----`

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why did you posted your private key here? It's very very bad behaviour to upload your private key to the any public website and even it's not secure to send via e-mail as well.